# How to correctly identify NFTs and FTs?

Tags: nft, cardano-address, token, cardano-api

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are some tokens: how would I differentiate NFTs from FTs in this case?

I am confused as "AdaFarm860" seems to be a NFT but it has a quantity of "4". I am  having some trouble figuring this out. Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you relay in the API data you can expect that a NFT has only 1 `mint_transaction`, with 1 `mint_quantit`y, and as result only 1 in `quantity`.

But that is not flawless... some asset can be minted one time, have the look and feel of a NFT and then it can be minted again, and now it is not a NFT anymore.

The only way to known if an asses will be for ever unique is to known the minting policy that produce it. You know the hash of that minting code, is the currency symbol or `policy_id`. That hash belongs to a unique source code. Sometimes that code is upload in some blockchain explorer and you can look at it.

There are two types of policies to mint assets in Cardano. Native scripts and Plutus Scripts.

Native scripts are easy to read. They can have something like this:
`{ "slot": 21561710, "type": "before" }`
That means that after that slot they can't be used again.

Plutus Scripts are complex. To create policies with one use only they consume an specific utxo. Because utxo exists only once, after they are consumed to create the nft you can be sure they can't run and mint again.

I hope it helps!